# html 5 date format

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Would we be able to change date format for inputs in html 5? Currently, my site is showing MM-DD-YYYY but I would like it to show DD-MM-YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, in HTML there is no syntax for DD-MM-YYYY format. Refer this [page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Date-Timezone/FormatdateMmmddyyyyhhmmdp.htm) . Somewhat it will help you.Or you could try this in javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();
// Array list of days.
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
// Array list of months.
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
// Calculate the number of the current day in the week.
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
// Calculate four digit year.
function fourdigits(number){
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                }
// Join it all together
today = days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
        months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
        date + ", " +
        (fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;
// Print out the data.
document.write(today);
// End -->
</script>
```